# I am using RealVNC to connect from my Windows 7 x64 machine to Mac OSX Lion

Tags: windows-7, mac, osx-lion, realvnc

I am using RealVNC to connect from my Windows 7 x64 machine to Mac OSX Lion.

The cursor I see on the Mac desktop is just a dot rather than a normal cursor. What setting have I missed that will give a familiar arrow cursor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the viewer machine, check your options and make sure "View only (inputs ignored)" is not checked.